# Read data (as USB data) from PC when Android device is connected to PC

Tags: android, usb, rfid, android-testing

I am working on a project where we are developing an Android app to read data from an RFID chip in an USB. The Android app works fine, reads the RFID data when the USB(with the RFID chip) is connected to the Android device. But I want to test the app when the Android device is connected to the PC, and mock the USB data(RFID data) from the PC. Is it possible? Has anyone tried this?
Thank you

Comment: This seems to be more about writing USB driver or re-using some on PC but not about Android.

Comment: By using umockdev , it is possible to mock usb devices http://stackoverflow.com/a/43917318/6180077